# GKE SSL Proxy NEG health check not working for TCP based services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I hav a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset) of `3` replicas of [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im). I have exposed them to GCP NEG using the following declaration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: ejabberd
annotations:
  cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"5222":{"name": "ejabberd-xmpp-production-neg"}, "5443":{"name": "ejabberd-http-production-neg"}}}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: ejabberd
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: xmpp
      port: 5222
      targetPort: 5222
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 5443
      targetPort: 5443
```

The health check is an HTTP endpoint at port 5443 that return HTTP 200 (OK) status code at path `/`.

The issue is that when i create a [SSL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl) the health check always fail but when i ssh into the pods and execute `$ curl localhost:5443/` i get a success response. TCP health checks didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Cloud Load Balancer not being able to access the ports. I fixed it by creating a firewall rule that allow the load balancer to access the specified port.

This achieved by running the following command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create fw-allow-health-check-and-proxy \
  --network=NETWORK_NAME \
  --action=allow \
  --direction=ingress \
  --target-tags=GKE_NODE_NETWORK_TAGS \
  --source-ranges=130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 \
  --rules=tcp:5443,tcp:5222
```

More can be found here [Attaching an external HTTP(S) load balancer to standalone NEGs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#attaching-ext-https-lb)